# `disable_with` to prevent double clicks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to add a disable_with to one of my button, however I can't get the correct syntax. Here's what I have tried so far.

before adding disable_with //this one work before however I can click cancel button multiple times

```
- content_for :cancel_button do
    #{cancel_shift_path(@shift)}
```

After adding disable_with //incorrect syntax

```
- content_for :cancel_button do
    #{cancel_shift_path(@shift), data: {disable_with: "Please wait"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to use is the button_tag helper:

```
<% content_for :cancel_button do %>
  <%= button_tag "#{cancel_shift_path(@shift)", data: { disable_with: "Please wait..."} %>
<% end %>
```

Here is the api reference: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-button_tag